# Haskell: "multiple" parameters with `newtype`

Tags: haskell

Disclaimer: I am very new to Haskell

I am trying to build an opaque, polymorphic queue ADT in haskell based on [this](http://www.randomhacks.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2007/02/08/haskell-queues-without-pointers/) design:

```
module Queue (Queue, empty, isEmpty, frontOf, enqueue, dequeue) where

data Queue a = Queue [a] [a] deriving Show

enqueue :: Queue a -> a -> Queue a
enqueue (Queue xs ys) y     = Queue xs (y:ys)

dequeue :: Queue a -> Maybe (Queue a)
dequeue (Queue [] [])       = Nothing
dequeue (Queue [] ys)       = dequeue (Queue (reverse ys) [])
dequeue (Queue (x:xs) ys)   = Just (Queue xs ys)
```

But I am trying to make it truly opaque using `newtype`:

```
module Queue (Queue, empty, isEmpty, frontOf, enqueue, dequeue) where

enqueue :: Queue a -> a -> Queue a
dequeue :: Queue a -> Maybe (Queue a)

newtype Queue a = Qimp ???

...function implementations
```

So my Question is, what do I put in place of `???`.

I've tried this:

```
newtype Queue a = Qimp ([] [])
```

But this seems to break the logic in my functions, for reasons that are probably obvious to a trained eye (but not obvious to me).

I seem to be in a pickle because my original implementation used two lists to implement a queue efficiently, but `newtype` requires exactly one parameter in the constructor. Is there a common/standard way to simulate multiple constructor parameters in a use of `newtype`?

Comment: In what way would `newtype` be more opaque than `data`?

Comment: Admittedly I'm not totally sure, but for example, couldn't a user of the Queue module do something along the lines of (assuming `q` is a Queue with some stuff in it): `let v = head (tail (head q))` and thus muck with the internals of the "ADT" themselves?

Comment: Whereas using `newtype` would hide the implementation details?

Comment: They can't do `head q` because `head` expects a list, but `q` is a `Queue`. They could do `case q of Queue front back -> head front`, but they can still do that if you use a `newtype`. The way to avoid this would be to not export `Queue`'s constructor.

Comment: You could use `newtype Queue a = Queue ([a],[a])`, but that would gain nothing compared with the `data` type you already have. What makes a type transparent of opaque is whether you export the (value) constructor from its module or not. `module Foo (Queue())` only exports the type.

Comment: I think it's cool that this question was downvoted. Never change, Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question seems to have been a case of the XY problem, so I'll try to both address the actual problem and answer the question you asked.

### When I define a `data` type with one constructor that takes two lists, can the user treat it as a tuple of lists?

No. A `data` definition creates its own distinct type (unlike a `type` definition, which just creates an alias).

### Are there any other issues with `data` with regard to opaqueness?

If you export the constructors of your data type, the user can use them through pattern matching to get at the lists that make up your queue. To prevent this, you should not export your constructors.

### What's the difference between a `newtype` and a `data` type?

A `newtype` is basically a restricted version of a `data` type that can be compiled more efficiently. The restrictions are that it can only have one constructor and that that constructor can only have one parameter.

There is a semantic difference between the two regarding laziness and non-termination (a data type can *contain* bottom, a *newtype* can only be bottom), but for the most part this does not matter and people simply use `newtype` whenever the restrictions are met to get better performance.

### Does using `newtype` make a type more opaque?

No, `newtype`s behave exactly the same as `data` type (modulo the laziness difference mentioned above). The same thing I said about the opaqueness of `data` types also applies to `newtype`s.

### Can a `newtype` have multiple parameters?

No, but it can have one parameter that is a tuple. You could define it like this:

```
data Queue a = Queue ([a], [a]) deriving Show
```

However there's very little reason why one would ever do that. The reason why you'd use a `newtype` over a `data` type is performance: You want to safe one level of indirection. However using a tuple just reintroduces the indirection you just saved, so it ends up exactly the same, performance wise.